# Does the prepared SQL statements in a stored procedure make the performance better?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, dynamic-sql

I know there have already been lots of question about stored procedure vs prepared SQL statements, but I want to find out something different - **if the prepared statements inside a procedure contribute to the performance of this stored procedure**, which means make it better.

I have this question because I was told following points when searching some introduction of these 2 skills.

- Stored procedure will store and compile your series of statements in
  db, which will reduce the overhead of transferring & compiling.
- Prepare statements will be compiled and cached in db for multiple
  access which lead to less overhead.

I am puzzled about these 'compile', 'store', and 'overhead' - a little bit abstract.

I use prepared statement to avoid re-parse if it will be called frequently.
**However should I use prepared statements (to cache & compile) inside a procedure? Since my procedure would have already been stored and compiled in DB, prepare something inside seems meaningless.** (compile what was compiled?)

edit with sample code:

```
Create or Replace procedure MY_PROCEDURE
Begin
    //totally meaningless here?
    declare sqlStmt varchar(300);
    declare stmt statement;

    set sqlStmt='update MY_TABLE set NY_COLUMN=? where NY_COLUMN=?';
    prepare stmt from sqlStmt;
    execute stmt using 2,1
    execute stmt using 4,3
        ..............
END
```

Is the the above one better than below, since it only parse the statement once? Or same, because statements in procedure will have been pre-compiled.

```
Create or Replace procedure MY_PROCEDURE
Begin
    update MY_TABLE set NY_COLUMN=2 where NY_COLUMN=1;
    update MY_TABLE set NY_COLUMN=4 where NY_COLUMN=3;
        ..............
END
```

Comment: personally, I don't think what db matters...point out if I'm wrong

Comment: what **concrete product** you're using will **MOST DEFINITELY** affect what can be said! These things are always **highly vendor-specific** and something for SQL Server might not apply to DB2 or Oracle **at all** (and vice-versa) !

Comment: @marc_s I agree, such as my sample code can only run in db2. But my question is kinds of general, since many popular db support ad-hoc SQL and procedure. I guess the key to handle of different db don't vary much. I'd like to know the similarities & differences if the answer of my question indeed depends on what concrete product used， such as no need to prepare in SQL server but it works in DB2. These will help me. Anyway, I haven't finish ur answer posted before. At least while reading, I really think it helps - 'general info in this is still relevant'.

Comment: @marc_s Do you mind to tell me how the db products you know handle prepare statements inside procedure differently as an answer below? And based on how they work, should I (not) do it in some concrete products respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DB2 actually the opposite may be true. Statements in an SQL routine are prepared when the routine is compiled. Dynamic SQL statements, as in your example, are prepared during the routine run time.

As a consequence, the preparation of dynamic statements will take into account the most current table and index statistics and other compilation environment settings, such as isolation level, while static statements will use the statistics that were in effect during the routine compilation or the latest bind.

If you want stable execution plans, use static SQL. If your statistics change frequently, you may want to use dynamic SQL (or make sure you rebind your routines' packages accordingly).

The same logic applies to Oracle PL/SQL routines, although the way to recompile static SQL differs -- you'll need to invalidate the corresponding routines.

Comment: @OGHaza - what part exactly confuses you? Static SQL is prepared once when you create the routine; dynamic SQL is prepared each time the routine is called in a new session. There is still some overhead even if you call it in the same session, as the compiler needs to look up each dynamic statement in the statement cache to determine if it's already there.

Comment: So every static SQL is also prepared in a procedure/routine, I do not need to change them into dynamic SQL and prepare them for performance.  If I do, will lead the dynamic SQL to be prepared when called every time, which make more overhead to call the procedure. Am I right?

Comment: Let me clarify more. I prepare a statement just to avoid re-parse if it's called multiple times. But since a procedure will parse all static statements inside when compiled, there won't be any overhead of paring a statement when call the procedure. No matter how many times the statement repeats in my procedure， actual running time won't be affected by preparing this statement. Please point out if I'm wrong

Comment: @AoboYang - that's correct. Once the procedure is compiled, which happens when you issue the CREATE PROCEDURE statement, there's no extra preparation at run time, except if there are any dynamic statements.

Comment: @mustaccio, btw I removed my comment before you replied because I realised you were referring to the title of the question. Still I think it is misleading to say the "opposite may be true" - because the key word really is **may**, in exceptional circumstances recompiling each time **may** improve performance.

Comment: @mustaccio The statement about frequency of statistics changing may be somewhat platform dependent.  If using DB2 for i (fka AS/400, iSeries) it has [Adaptive Query Processing](http://www.ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/administrator/db2/Protection-From-Slow-Queries/) which will decide whether to re-evaluate the access plan while a query is running, if it is running "long" (such as 2 seconds).

Comment: @WarrenT - it appears that the article you linked to speaks about dynamic SQL, but I don't know DB2 for i well enough to say if it applies to SQL routines.

Comment: @mustaccio AQP analyses every query running long enough for it to have enough run time stats to analyze ("approximately 2 seconds"). If the cached plan has been running well for months, AQP will still check it and change the plan if it sees it can do better.  This applies to any type of query, like a coach always watching on the sidelines, sending in a new player if one seems to be tired or performing poorly.

Comment: But AQP is (currently) only part of DB2 running on **IBM i** 7.1

Answer (score 3):

When you first run a stored procedure the database engine parses the procedure and works out the optimal query plan to use when executing it - it then stores this query plan so that every time you run the procedure it doesn't have to recalculate it.

You can see this youself in Management Studio. If you `CREATE` or `ALTER` the stored procedure in question, then open a new query and use:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

In that same query window run the stored procedure. In the messages tab of the result the first message will be something like:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 1038 ms, elapsed time = 1058 ms.
```

This is the overhead, execute the query again and you will see that the parse and compile time is now 0.

When you prepare a statement in code you get to take advantage of the same benefit. If you query is `'SELECT * FROM table WHERE @var = '+$var`, each time you run that query SQL Server has to parse it and calculate the optimal execution plan. If you use a prepared statement `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ?`, SQL Server will calculate the optimal execution plan the first time you run the prepared statement, and from then on it can reuse the execution plan as with a stored procedure. The same goes if the statement you are executing is `'EXEC dbo.myProc @var = '+$var`, SQL Server would still have to parse this statement each time so a prepared statement should still be used.

You do not need to prepare statements that you write inside stored procedures because they are already compiled as shown above - they are prepared statements in themselves.

On thing you should be aware of when using stored procedure and prepared statements is **parameter sniffing**.

SQL Server calculates and stores the optimal execution plan for the first variables used, if you happen to execute the stored procedure with some unusual variable on the first run, the execution plan stored may be completely suboptimal for the sorts of variables you typically use.

If you find you can execute a stored procedure from Management Studio and it takes say 2 seconds to execute, but performing the same action in your application takes 20 seconds, it's probably as a result of parameter sniffing.

Comment: bah, this was tagged `sql-server` a minute ago right? The more general info in this is still relevant so will leave it here anyway, just ignore references to Management Studio...

Comment: yeah, actually i don't think what kind of db I use will affect my question much. Lucky to tag the wrong tag before or I can't read ur answer